# Understanding and implementing the dprime measure in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, metric, d-prime

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_index#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,the%20signal%20or%20noise%20distribution.), the dprime score (aka 'sensitivity index') can be expressed as

$$ d' = Z(\text{hit rate}) - Z(\text{false alarm rate})$$

hit rate (aka recall aka sensitivity) and false alarm rate (equal to 1-specificity). These quantities are point estimates, that is each is a single scalar between 0 and 1.

Z represents the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of the Gaussian distribution. I don't understand how this is supposed to be computed from a single value. A distribution of hit rates and a distribution of false alarm rates would be needed.

In the Wikipedia article, d-prime is also expressed as the Z score of the area of the receiver-operator characteristic times the square root of two.

$$ d' = \sqrt{2} Z(AUC)$$

**Q: Is the use of the Z-score in this notation meant to represent prediction and ground truth values that have been Z-normalized?**

Is the code below a valid implementation of dprime?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import math
Z = norm.ppf

y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
y_pred = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
dprime = math.sqrt(2) * Z(roc_auc_score(y_true,y_pred))
print(dprime)
```

This prints inf, as the classifier has made no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the wikipedia page, it says

> ... where function Z(p), p ∈ [0,1], is the inverse of the cumulative
> distribution function of the Gaussian distribution.

So, the input to $Z$ function is a single value in $[0,1]$, which can be hit rate, false alarm rate or AUC, which means you don't need a distribution. It doesn't say but it should be the inverse CDF of standard gaussian.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please comment on my updated Python code? I used norm.ppf from scipy.stats as Z.

Comment: @andandandand you're welcome, it seems correct